# Linechart with JSON object in dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm new to dc.js and I want to create a simple line chart with object.

**The Object (/signalData.json):**

```
"1": 10, 
"2": 20,
"3": 30, 
"4": 40,
"5": 50, 
"6": 60
```

The keys should be the x coordinates and the values should be the y coordinates

I Tried something like this but it does not work:

```js
var data = {
  "1": 10,
  "2": 20,
  "3": 30,
  "4": 40,
  "5": 50,
  "6": 60
};

var dataModel = [{
  "keys": Object.keys(data).map(function(d) {
    return +d;
  }),
  "values": Object.values(data)
}, ]

signalCF = crossfilter(dataModel)

signalDim = signalCF.dimension(function(d) {
  return d.keys
}, true)
signalGroup = signalDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  return d.values
});


var linechart = dc.lineChart("#linechart")
  .width(700)
  .height(300)
  .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 6]))
  .renderArea(true)
  .brushOn(false)
  .renderDataPoints(true)
  .clipPadding(10)
  .yAxisLabel("This is the Y Axis!")
  .dimension(signalDim)
  .group(signalGroup);

linechart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter2/1.4.0-alpha.6/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.1/dc.js"></script>
<div id="linechart"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? Do you get an error? Do you see anything? `Object.keys()` returns a string array, try `Object.keys(data).map(function(d) { return +d; })` instead to cast the strings to numbers

Comment: It shoes the d.keys in the chart but the d.values are NaN

Comment: Please create a [mre] so we can debug with you

Comment: I added more Information. Now this is all my code. I hope that helps you

Comment: If you need more just let me know :)

Comment: I've turned your code into a runnable snippet. Can you confirm that what you see here is also what you see locally? Including the small dots at the top?

Comment: Thank you. Yes thats what i see locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made an incorrect assumption about the data structure. You need an array with one value per tick, not an array with all values directly after each other:

```
[{ keys: [], values: [] }]
```

becomes

```
[{ key: number, value: number }, { key: number, value: number }, ...]
```

```js
var data = {
  "1": 10,
  "2": 20,
  "3": 30,
  "4": 40,
  "5": 50,
  "6": 60
};

var dataModel = Object.keys(data).map(function(d) {
  return {
    key: +d,
    value: data[d]
  };
})

signalCF = crossfilter(dataModel)

signalDim = signalCF.dimension(dc.pluck("key"))
signalGroup = signalDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});


var linechart = dc.lineChart("#linechart")
  .width(700)
  .height(300)
  .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 6]))
  .renderArea(true)
  .brushOn(false)
  .renderDataPoints(true)
  .clipPadding(10)
  .yAxisLabel("This is the Y Axis!")
  .dimension(signalDim)
  .group(signalGroup);

linechart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter2/1.4.0-alpha.6/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.1/dc.js"></script>
<div id="linechart"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Bit is there a possibility to make ist my way? Ist would be nice if i just could Feed the object or a array series as Data?

Comment: Not that I know of, and I tried to find it for you. You take an array of arrays of numbers `[10, 20...]` and try to use those for `.reduceSum()`. But you can't add/subtract arrays from arrays, so it returns `NaN` and the plot breaks

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much. Is there a way to get in touch with you? I'm just getting startet with dc.js and i cant find good resources online maybe you can help me by couple things if you want to? :)

Comment: I don't have any experience with dc, only with d3.js. The best way if you have any questions is to ask them on StackOverflow, there are a lot more people who answer them. Just make sure your questions are clear and haven't been asked here before, I'm sure you'll get answers quickly. The best way to learn d3 is always through examples, there are a lot of them online! Must be the same for dc.

Comment: Welcome to dc.js, Felix! Another good option for broad topics that don’t fit the Q&A format is the [dc.js users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!forum/dc-js-user-group), although you will probably find most answers here on SO.